# How can the FileUpload field in Laravel Filament directory be changed dynamically?

Tags: php, laravel, forms, laravel-filament

I have a form with a file upload. When i upload the file, it saves into my desired **`public/uploads/documents`** location. However, i want every user should save it's files ***`public/uploads/documents/userfolder`*** based on user foldername on my client's details table. I am using Relation manager to save client's details and uploaded files. How do i achieve this?

`FileUpload::make('name')->disk('public')->directory('documents/'.$foldername),`

I want to get the $foldername from the related Parent model in the table